# Is java native memory used in Log4j2 ? I found many log in native memory instead of heap

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j

We have a java app started by running Main function, we also start embedded jetty in springboot as webcontainer. I found java  head reached max size  , but heap usage is low and java run out native memory killed by OS

There are many 64MB memory in pmap. I dump some memory blocks and found many log in it. The log time is various, it seems log still in memory even days passed.
for exmaple

```
2019-03-23T05:50:46,851 661258664 [xxxxxx] INFO
2019-03-27T06:00:12,040 1029308155 [xxxxxxxx] INFO .........
```

We use log4j2 and slf4j as log tool. Logs was printed by jetty thread which name start with 'qtp'. 
We set  `immediateFlush="false"` and `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"`

I don't know why the log content are NOT in heap. Is log4j2  using java native memory when cache or write log ? Is it possible log4j2 memory leak?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect what you are seeing is a side effect of a little-known feature of Log4j 2: [garbage-free logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/garbagefree.html).

Since log4j 2.6, the library takes extreme care to **not allocate any temporary objects** during steady-state logging (there is some allocation of temporary objects during initialization and configuration).

Other logging libraries that don’t have this feature will typically allocate many LogEvent objects, as well as Strings, `char[]` arrays and `byte[]` arrays. These are typically very short-lived and quickly collected, but significant logging will fill up the Young Generation and contribute to promotions.

On the HotSpot JVM even **minor collections are stop-the-world** collections with all current GC algorithms: Serial, Parallel, Concurrent, CMS, and G1. (This may become less impactful with [Shenandoah](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/shenandoah/Main) and [ZGC](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/zgc/Main), but these collectors are still experimental as of this writing. Also note that [Zing/Azul](https://www.azul.com/products/zing/pgc/) has a pauseless collector, however that work has not been contributed to OpenJDK.)

Log4j 2 sidesteps this by avoiding allocation and reusing memory where possible.

Comment: Second-last paragraph is incorrect, and has been so for > 20 years.

Comment: @user207421 What do you base this on? You can easily verify that minor collections are stop-the-world in HotSpot by enabling the `‑XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` flag. This is rapidly becoming a major issue as the trend is for application heaps to get larger with more live objects.

Comment: The linked page does not say anything about using off-heap memory, though.

Comment: I was guessing this was stack memory, but I could be wrong. Does the application use a memory mapped file appender?

Comment: @Remko Popma memory mapped file appender? Do you means something like RollingRandomAccessFile appender? We using RollingRandomAccessFile appender. I readed you link and checked source code.  ByteBuffer is used in the appender . But it seems no memory leak when app is running and it only apply and reuse 256K native memory. So i doubt if i am right. But many log content is in momry block.

Comment: @FFMan I wondered if you were using the log4j 2 MemoryMappedFileAppender, thanks for the clarification. So I’m guessing you ended up doing a memory dump of the buffers used by log4j. But I could be wrong. Not sure if there’s really a problem here though.